# Каким образом можно заменить байт в файле, не перезаписывая его полностью?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким образом можно заменить байт в файле, не перезаписывая его полностью? У меня в файле большие бинарные данные в виде пар ключ-значение, и нужно каждый раз менять точечно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чисто программно это выглядит так:

```
with open('sample_data/README.md', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(1)
    f.write(bytes([ord('H')]))
```

В Google Colab проверил, поменял один байт в файле, который там всегда есть. В файле одна буква (вторая) поменялась:

```
THis directory includes a few sample datasets...
```

Пояснения:

- файл открывается на чтение и запись `r+` и в двоичном режиме `b`
- на нужную позицию файла переход делается с помощью `file.seek`
- после перехода на нужную позицию можно как читать `read`, так и писать `write` нужное количество байтов
- открывать файл лучше с использованием конструкции `with`, чтобы закрылся он автоматически по окончании блока кода

Answer (score 3):

1. открываешь файл
2. перемещаешь позицию на нужное место
3. считываешь данные
4. записываешь данные
5. закрываешь файл

только учтите, все равно меньше кластера принципиально нельзя считать/записать
вернее API такое позволяют, но на уровне жестких дисков все равно будет считано и записано 4КБ и больше